# Which application to preview .md files?

Tags: macos

Is there an application to preview `markdown` files (`.md` files) on OSX (for instance on Maverick)?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The superuser question, [Markdown Live Preview Editor?](https://superuser.com/questions/174976/markdown-live-preview-editor), provides a wealth of options:

- [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/)
- [TextMate](http://macromates.com)
- [Mou](http://mouapp.com/)
- [Marked](http://markedapp.com/)
- [MarkdownLive](https://github.com/rentzsch/markdownlive)
- [Atom](https://github.com/atom/markdown-preview)
- [Marked 2](http://marked2app.com)
- [MacDown](http://macdown.uranusjr.com)

In additional to those, you can install a [markdown QuickLook plugin](https://github.com/sbarex/QLMarkdown) for Finder based previews.

## MarkdownLive

[image: MarkdownLive]

## Mou

[image: Mou]

## Marked 2

[image: Marked2]

Comment: The `QuickLook` plug-in does not work with `Mavericks`.

Comment: Regarding the QuickLook plug-in, please consider adding your voice to https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown/issues/29; or, as the project is open source, having a go at fixing up the code.

Comment: http://alternativeto.net/software/mou/?platform=mac has updated list of markdown preview (and/or) editor

Comment: Fyi, yhe QuickLook plugin does work with El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: For me, based on running through your ist, **MacDown** was the simplest to install and use quickly. Thanks for showing the options!

Comment: Mou has been abandoned essentially. No update in a couple of years.

Comment: Just to add.  I tried the BBEdit markdown preview and the default style is quite plain, but I found you can [download a custom CSS file](https://www.bbeditextras.org/preview-css-files/) to make it look more stylish.

Comment: toland/qlmarkdown [has been abandoned, and replaced](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown/issues/102) with [sbarex/QLMarkdown](https://github.com/sbarex/QLMarkdown), which installs `QLMarkdown.app`, which must be run to activate the plugin. This is what you get with `brew install --cask qlmarkdown` today, thankfully.

Answer (score 21):

## Visual Studio Code

[image: VSCode Markdown Example]
Source: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_markdown-preview

Microsoft's Visual Studio Code has been surprisingly pleasant to use as a general purpose IDE, and elegantly renders markdown.

Comment: You can right-click on the editor Tab and select Open Preview (⇧⌘V) or use the Command Palette (⇧⌘P) to run the Markdown: Open Preview to the Side command (⌘K V). **The Open Preview Tab is the guy that looks like a book with a magnifying glass.**

Answer (score 19):

I would like to add the excellent - and open source - [MacDown](http://macdown.uranusjr.com/) to the list.

Answer (score 12):

If you would like markdown to be read with Quick Look, you can use [QLMarkdown](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown).

You can install it either by:

- Download the `QLMarkdown.qlgenerator` in either `~/Library/QuickLook` (current user) or `/Library/QuickLook` (all users).
- Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), run `brew install --cask qlmarkdown` in the Terminal. *(updated)*

If you find qlmarkdown Applications, right click and open the app, it will get around the Apple security check warning.

After that, you should be able to view markdown files.

Comment: Why the downvote? A mod suggested I post this here after [posting it on a duplicate question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297247/64937). I had thought it would be welcome here.

Comment: If I had to guess, It's probably because the accepted answer already linked and mentioned the QuickLook generator for Markdown files and there is no need to have redundant answers.

Comment: The new version of QLMarkdown is here now: https://github.com/sbarex/qlmarkdown

Comment: ```Error: `brew cask` is no longer a `brew` command. Use `brew <command> --cask` instead.```

So the update to the command would be:

```$brew install --cask qlmarkdown```

Answer (score 8):

The perfect preview tool for Markdown is [Marked 2](http://marked2app.com/) which gives a preview of your Markdown and watches the file so that every time you save in an editor your preview is updated.

It also supports custom pre-processors so you can use extra markup such as critic, custom CSS so you can have a preview that looks however you wish and tools to export the result in a variety of formats. It can even track an entire folder and start previewing a different file when you start to edit it.

Taken together all that means that you can write your Markdown in any editor you like and preview and output easily.

You might want to think about installing [qlmarkdown](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown/) which gives you the ability to preview MarkDown files properly in the Finder using QuickLook.

Comment: As of today, qlmarkdown [isn't working properly on Catalina 10.15.4](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown/issues/98)

Comment: The QLMarkdown project linked to seems to be abandoned, but there is a new QLMarkdown now at https://github.com/sbarex/qlmarkdown, which I can confirm works on macOS 12.3...

Answer (score 7):

If you are using sublimetext, then you can use **MARKDOWN PREVIEW**  package from package manager.

It has multiple styles like GITHUB, HTML and etc.

https://www.sublimetext.com

https://facelessuser.github.io/MarkdownPreview/

Comment: Inside Sublime you will need to go to `Tools` and install the `Command Palette`. To preview a Markdown file go to `Tools` --> `Command Palette...` --> `Markdown Preview: Preview in Browser` and choose `markdown`.

Answer (score 6):

There is also **Markoff** ([App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/markoff/id1084713122), [GitHub](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Markoff)), a pure viewer for CommonMark files:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you'd rather not install a new application, there are browser extensions for this. I use [Markdown Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk) for Google Chrome, which allows Chrome to open markdown files and displays them like GitHub would. Then just set your browser as the default application to open .md files (or use open with if you'd rather have an editor be the default program).

Comment: @Jackson1442 this actually is an answer providing a solution to the question asked. It could be improved by explaining in more detail how this plugin can be used to render locally-stored Markdown files.

Comment: @patrix - oops! I misread this answer. *Really* badly! My apologies, Barry!

Comment: I think this is a very reasonable approach, but I don't necessarily agree with making a browser the default program for viewing `.md` files. I write in Markdown, and having a browser as the default app would be a nuisance. But it wouldn't be as big a nuisance as installing XCode - it makes itself the default handler for `.md` files,... and when you allow it to try, it wants to download more stuff! Sheesh! At 5GB, you think they could find room for a markdown app!

Comment: don't forget you might need to give the plugin access to file urls - type `chrome://extensions` in the address bar, then select options for the `Markdown Viewer` and switch access to file urls to `on`

Answer (score 2):

A lot of ideas here, but most of them are old, some even out-of-date. I came here looking for a *previewer* - not an *editor* (as the question says). However, it seems most of the answers are *editors*. So I'll add this answer for the editor I use. It's still actively under development, open-source, fairly easy-to-use and flexible: [Typora](https://typora.io/).

Answer (score 2):

There is also a newish option called Obsidian - https://obsidian.md/, which more of a networked thought tool (like [Roam Research](https://roamresearch.com/)) but build on top of markdown files.

[image: Screenshot of preview page]

Comment: How does this help to preview .md files?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the preview screen

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for: simple and easy to browse a folder structure with .md files!
10 000 thanks !

Comment: This must be amongst the most underrated responses ever supplied on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Terminal, I made [a thing in Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mdr).

Answer (score 1):

[Panic Nova](https://nova.app/) can view the file:

- open the file in Panic Nova
- click the preview icon ( eye )

Answer (score 0):

I just set a proportional serif font in VS Code, add some limited colors, and the normal, inline display is fine.
[image]