# How can I read markdown files with QuickLook?

Tags: quicklook, markdown

I would like to be able to read markdown (.md) files with [Quick Look](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quick_Look). Unfortunately, it just appears like this:

[image: Markdown file macOS Quick Look]

Is there any way that I can be able to see the contents of this file? I don't care whether it's in rendered or unrendered format, just that I can see it somehow.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no setting in macOS to enable markdown support. However, Quick Look does allow for third party plugins to extend the base behavior. The [QLMarkdown](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown) plugin is one such plugin that allows Markdown files to be read.

You can install it either by:

- Download the `QLMarkdown.qlgenerator` in either `~/Library/QuickLook` (current user) or `/Library/QuickLook` (all users).
- Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh), run `brew install toland-qlmarkdown` in the Terminal

After that, you should be able to view markdown files.

### Getting it to work on macOS Catalina - [Source](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown/issues/98)

If you got the security warning as shown below, go to `System Preferences / Security & Privacy / General` and click `Allow Anyway` at the bottom.
[image]
Now try to Quicklook a markdown file again. If it still doesn't work, run the following commands in your terminal.

```
brew install toland-qlmarkdown
xattr -cr ~/Library/QuickLook/QLMarkdown.qlgenerator
qlmanage -r
qlmanage -r cache
killall Finder  # relaunch finder
```

It should hopefully work now.

Comment: In case anybody is wondering, no I am not associated with this QLMarkdown. I self-answered this question because I had a problem and wanted to share my solution in case others ran into it too.

Comment: Good answer, can you please repost it on the question linked above (which covers the same topic but mentions the plugin only briefly)?

Comment: @patrix Would that be appropriate? It looks like that question was just looking for applications. Also, wouldn't that make my question a duplicate of that one?

Comment: The question is broad enough to allow both applications and QL plugins (preview can be both, somehow)

Comment: @patrix How does the duplicate policy work on this site? I got burned earlier today on Sci-fi/Fantasy SE by asking a question that was marked as a duplicate because another question's answer addressed my question. I would hate for somebody to mark my question as a duplicate because the other question now has the answer.

Comment: @patrix [According to this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/191265), the Community user will flag it as an exact duplicate if I repost that answer. Are you sure it's okay for me to do this? Sorry if I'm sounding to paranoid, just want to make sure I do things the right way.

Comment: I've already closed your question here as a duplicate to the other one. Reposting the answer may raise an auto flag for the mods but we easily clear this flag without harm

Comment: @patrix Thanks for clarifying. I wish the notification system would let users know when their questions are closed. I didn't realize that had happened until you mentioned it.