# Can't get QLMarkdown to work in Monterey

Tags: finder, homebrew, quicklook, markdown, quicklook-plugin

I'm trying to do what should be a fairly simple task: have Finder and Quick Look view .md and .markdown files as if they had the extension .txt. As per [previous](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/297246/how-can-i-read-markdown-files-with-quicklook) [answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/which-application-to-preview-md-files) on this topic, I had installed the QLMarkdown plugin in my /Library/Quicklook to make this happen, and it was working fine for a while.

Recently I had a hardware disaster that required Apple to wipe and replace my hard drive, with the new one running Monterey. In this new system, the QLMarkdown plugin is not working. I tried copying the latest version (1.3.6) into the /Library/Quicklook and, as per the [readme](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown/#readme), I ran qlmanage -r in the terminal to refresh. Then I got an error from Apple saying it would not run because Apple could not check it for malicious software. No option to override.

The previous answers suggest I could install Homebrew and run "brew cask install qlmarkdown", but following the [Homebrew install instructions](https://brew.sh/) wound up causing a system freeze and reboot - and QuickLook wasn't working any better after that.

How do I get QuickLook to recognize Markdown on Monterey under these circumstances?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Short answer

If you've (recently) done `brew install --cask qlmarkdown`, you probably just need to run QLMarkdown.app to activate the plugin.

If you can't/don't use homebrew, make sure you're using **this** version of qlmarkdown: [sbarex/QLMarkdown](https://github.com/sbarex/QLMarkdown) — and follow the instructions there.

### Long answer

For a long time, the QLMarkdown plugin was this one: [toland/qlmarkdown](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown), and that's what you'd get even if you installed it from homebrew.  That version basically consists of a  "qlmarkdown.qlgenerator" file which needs to be copied to some particular folder — as described in the question above.

Unfortunately, that project [has been abandoned](https://github.com/toland/qlmarkdown/issues/102).

The good news is that it's been replaced with [sbarex/QLMarkdown](https://github.com/sbarex/QLMarkdown), which I can report works great under Monterey.  In fact, if you do a `brew cask --install qlmarkdown` *today*, **this is the version you get** — which is very helpful!

**But** this new project works slightly differently: instead of installing a "qlmarkdown.qlgenerator" file somewhere, the plugin is delivered as an app (QLMarkdown.app) which you need to run before the extension is available.
(You may also need to enable the extension in **System Preferences** > **Extensions** > **Quick Look**.)

If you've run `brew install --cask qlmarkdown` relatively recently, *you've probably got this updated version*, so the solution is probably just "run the app". (BTW you might also want to pass `--no-quarantine` to `brew install` so it skips that tediousness, assuming you trust the cask of course )

(BTW I've seen some chatter suggesting that "*.qlgenerator" is deprecated as a way of installing QuickLook plugins since Catalina, but I can't find confirmation of it, and AFAICS some plugins in that style still work, e.g. [qlvideo](https://github.com/Marginal/QLVideo). ‍♂️ )

Answer (score 0):

After setting up a new M2 Mac Mini from an Intel MacBook Pro Time Machine backup, I had to delete QLMarkdown (with AppCleaner) and reinstall with `brew install --cask qlmarkdown`, then click "open anyway" in: "System Settings…  Privacy & Security". Works fine now.